# Join the same tour by two people from different departures (countries)?

Tags: italy, tours

Is it possible for two people from different departures (different countries, I am from USA, another person from Chile) to join into the same tour group and travel together?

We plan to travel to Italy in Jan 2014 together, and would like to joint the same tour group. Does anyone know if this is possible?

I been looking at globusjourneys and virgin-vacations for tours.

The tour, that we are looking at, starts at the same city, like Rome. But the concern that I have is that we will be flying to Rome from different countries.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to join a tour starting at different places - i.e. with flights from different places? Or are you just concerned about being of different nationalities?

Comment: Well, I guess the tour will start from the same city (Rome for example). But we will be flying from different places.

Answer (score 6):

With these bus tours; I find that there are usually two different options for arriving at the starting city:

**1)** You can book/purchase the tour INCLUDING flights to and from the starting city.

or

**2)** You can book/purchase the tour EXCLUDING flights to and from the starting city. Sometimes the tour uses terms such as 'make your own way'.

The only downside with making your own way is that you would not be picked up from the airport and would need to find your starting hotel by yourself. It's not as easy as it seems as bus tour hotels are usually located on the outskirts of the city.

Comment: I think from what I am reading on virgin-vacations that they would still meet you at airport, if you tell them details of the flight.