# Which countries in Southeast Asia require travel insurance proof?

Tags: international-travel, paperwork, insurance, southeast-asia

I've heard that some countries may require some travel insurance proof when entering to the country.

Which countries require that and what kind of insurance?

Do they accept any standard travel insurance such as that included with some Credit Cards, VISAs or [personal banking](http://personal.natwest.com/personal/current-accounts/existing-current-account-customers/advantage-gold.html) although there is no any proof or some more specific certificates or papers (e.g. for Malaria)?

Specifically I'm interested for Hong Kong, Vietnam, Singapore, Philippines, Malaysia and Thailand.

Similar question, but for [Europe](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23633/use-of-travel-insurance-while-going-to-europe).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

None. I have visited all those countries and I wasn't asked about insurance by any country (we have free medical care back in my home country but I think that's irrelevant).

A note about your credit card's insurance: if you plan to use it, just make sure you are eligible for it before leaving the country. In most cases, you have to buy the ticket using that particular card and/or have spent a minimum amount using that card. I tried to make a claim a few months back. It didn't really went good.

Comment: Can confirm, I have never been asked for an insurance proof - anywhere in Asia.

Comment: Thanks. I was on 2014/2015 in Hong Kong, Macau, Singapore, Philippines, Malaysia and Thailand and everything was fine.

Answer (score 4):

Thailand talked about having tourists provide proof of insurance upon arrival, as too many travelers have skipped out on hospital bills (scooter crashes, etc). They have also talked about implementing insurance coverage for travelers paid by a fee to be collected upon arrival.  But none of these ideas have been implemented and likely won't be in the near future.

With the exception of the Philippines, none of the other countries have asked me for proof of insurance when visiting recently (haven't been to PI in recent years).

Comment: For what it's worth I've never been asked for proof of travel insurance when entering the Philippines. Neither has anyone else I know who comes here regardless of visa status or length of stay. Technically I'm sure they can, but they never do. I have been stopped travelling into Hong Kong and asked about how much cash I had to support myself, but nothing about travel insurance (and I didn't even need to show the cash).

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that the Philippines did, rather, I have not been to the Philippines recently so could not provide firsthand feedback.  But have been to all the other countries the OP mentioned.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I understood that -- just adding a data point to complete the set.