# Buy flight tickets in advance or just in time for a multi-city trip in Europe

Tags: air-travel, europe, planning, international-travel

I'm planning a first time travel from Brazil to Europe. I'm thinking of visiting 4 or 5 countries (United Kingdom, France, Germany, Greece and maybe Netherlands or Czech Republic).

Is it best (money-wise) to buy the plane tickets to travel around Europe at the airport or to buy in advance? I found PaylessFlights that I can buy multi-destination flights before I travel, but I don't know if they charge more or less than cheap companies (like Rayanair).

I'm asking because I could buy ticket to go to a country and come back from another.

Comment: Off-topic remark: also consider trains for Netherlands/France/Germany. Connection Amsterdam-Paris is really good for example. If you go by high-speed rails, you'd better also book in advance.

Comment: The question still the same hehe. Book in advance or buy on time? Thanks for advice.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2952/flight-tickets-buy-two-weeks-before-even-during-holiday-seasons/2967#2967 Does it answer your question?

Comment: It's not a duplicate, I think. The other one asks in general, I asked flights for travelling inside Europe, that have this cheap companies...

Comment: Note that if you are a Brazilian citizens, you will need to [produce an itinerary and return ticket out of the Schengen area](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22065/visa-for-a-chilean-citizen-joining-a-tour-from-a-us-agency/22067#22067) at the relevant border (and possibly the same of the UK) so you might need to book at least some of the tickets in advance.

Comment: @Tsuharesu They work more-or-less in the same way, the main difference is that there is only one set of conditions (possibly two with easyjet's Flex tickets) and you can only book tickets through their website. For low-cost companies, the answer is definitely buy as soon as possible and if they are not cheaper now, they are not going to be cheaper the day before. You definitely shouldn't buy a Ryanair ticket at the airport (if that's possible at all they will charge you extortionate prices; even simply having them print a boarding pass is notoriously expensive).

Comment: Also they don't always fly from the same airports than other airlines (Easyjet mostly does, Ryanair almost never, others vary) so you can't show up at a large airport and expect to find good tickets on low-cost airlines. Reaching Ryanair airports with public transport is often difficult so you need to factor that in and make a decision beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my various comments, buying late is almost always a bad idea, especially for low-cost airlines. The main answer to [Flight tickets: buy two weeks before even during holiday seasons?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2952/flight-tickets-buy-two-weeks-before-even-during-holiday-seasons) explains how this works and also more or less applies to low-cost airlines (perhaps even more so as very few people will ever change their booking with low-cost airlines as it's almost impossible or at least quite expensive compared to the price of the ticket itself).

Additionally, low-cost airlines are not particularly happy to sell tickets at the airport, an important aspect of their business model is to minimize customer contact and have everything go through their websites. For example, Ryanair is notorious for charging seemingly absurd prices if you forgot to print your boarding pass at home before coming to the airport. If you value flexibility, this is definitely not the right choice.

Consequently, you can compare prices between your multi-destination ticket, regular one-way tickets and low-cost fares now. If low-cost airlines are not cheaper, it's not going to get better shortly before your trip. On the other hand, if you value flexibility, you will have to decide if the price difference is worth it for you. You might also want to consider rail passes (at least for Germany, the Netherlands and the Czech Republic; Greece is not well connected to the European rail network and long-distance trains in France are best booked in advance).

Comment: Thanks for all the tips :) Maybe I can get night trains too, so I don't spend with hotels too hehe

Answer (score 1):

It is almost always a bad idea to buy at the airport (you may also have trouble, as many countries require you to book tickets several hours/days in advance), in fact, there are several studies that show that the best time to book airfare is 4-8 weeks in advance.
[Source one](http://www.cheapair.com/blog/travel-tips/top-10-tips-for-booking-cheap-flights/)
[Source two](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/2013-01-22/travel/sns-201301220000--tms--travelpkctnxf-a20130122-20130122_1_airlines-offer-average-fare-cheapest-tickets)
.