# Backpacking to Europe and Northern Africa on one way ticket - will I face issues with immigration?

Tags: schengen, us-citizens, proof-of-onward-travel

I'm planning on backpacking from NYC with a USA passport to Portugal → Spain → Morocco → Paris → back to NYC. I know for sure that the trip will be less than a month. I bought a one way ticket because I'm not sure of the exact date that I will be returning.

Will I have any problems with immigration with any of these countries if I don't have a return ticket? Has anyone with a US passport traveled to multiple countries before on a one way ticket? Did you encounter any problems at immigration?

Comment: You don't necessarily need a *return* ticket, just an onward one.

Comment: The only answer to this question is a definitely maybe.  It's at the discretion of immigration officer who interviews you.  I have entered several European countries, including the UK, without an onward ticket with no issue.  Others might not be allowed to even board the flight over.

Comment: What is an *imas* USA passport?

Comment: imaš from https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/imati . "(I) have a US passport", possibly.

Comment: No answers will help you because many people do travel with one way tickets but are not questioned by immigration in depth. You do not know if you may be questioned in depth, and if the immigration officer will accept your explanation. Basically the answer to you is **it depends**

Comment: If possible I would have a one way ticket out of the schegan area for instance portugal to the uk I did this one time Air france didnt let me board. It cost like 10 euro instead of the 1500 ticket back to LA they insisted I buy. Very much depends on who is checking you in bit they can refuse to let you board.

Comment: One way you can get around immigration problems because of having a one way ticket that I use extensively (I almost always buy one way tickets because my itinerary changes) is to take advantage of the [24-hour Reservation Requirement](https://www.transportation.gov/airconsumer/notice-24hour-reservation) and buy a one way return (back home) ticket just before I depart. Immediately I land at destination **and** clear immigration, I cancel the ticket. I did this on my UK trip last week and indeed the immigration officer demanded to see my return ticket. Without it I would have been denied entry!

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look at the steps in your itinerary.

1. You fly into Portugal. Here they might like to see onwards travel from the Schengen area (usually the check-in agents are more insistent than immigration officers). You show them the Spain - Morocco ticket as that's valid onward travel.
2. You fly from Spain to Portugal. No immigration checks here and in any case you have your ticket to Morocco.
3. You fly from Portugal to Morocco. Here you show them your ticket from Morocco to Paris.
4. You fly from Morocco to Paris. That's the only part of the itinerary which is problematic - you **wouldn't** have valid proof of onwards travel.

To solve this issue you have several options:

- Buy a throwaway onwards ticket from a [specialized travel agent](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59239/difference-between-onwardflights-com-and-flyonward-com).
- Buy a cheap ticket out of the Schengen area, e.g. a Ryanair flight to London.
- Take a risk and show up without proof of onward travel. I'd say the biggest issue here is being denied from boarding by the airline. As for the immigration officers, [there's no actual requirement](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/24769/9009) to be in possession of valid proof of travel. However you would be in a harder position to show that you're planning to leave the Schengen area at the end of your stay.